# GhostscriptError: -100 while using camelot-py

Tags: ghostscript, python-camelot

Windows 10, Python 3.7.4, Ghostscript 9.5.2

After having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529975/camelot-pythonoserror-exception-access-violation-writing-0x00000080) problem I've installed camelot from the repository. Havn't got this error again, but got this new one:

```
File "data_extract2.py", line 17, in get_data_tables
return camelot.read_pdf(daily_url, pages="all")
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py", line 117, in read_pdf
**kwargs
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py", line 172, in parse
p, suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs=layout_kwargs
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\lattice.py", line 403, in extract_tables
self.generate_image()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\lattice.py", line 220, in generate_image
with Ghostscript(*gs_call, stdout=null) as gs:
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\camelot\ext\ghostscript_init.py", line 95, in Ghostscript
stderr=kwargs.get("stderr", None),
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\camelot\ext\ghostscript_init.py", line 39, in init
rc = gs.init_with_args(instance, args)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\camelot\ext\ghostscript_gsprint.py", line 173, in init_with_args
raise GhostscriptError(rc)
camelot.ext.ghostscript._gsprint.GhostscriptError: -100
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You're going to need to get the Ghostscript back channel output somehow and post that (no I've no clue how you can do that with Python/Camelot). Or, alternatively, the Ghostscript command and the input file. Though it looks to me like you might be using gsprint, not Ghostscript, which is a slightly different beast. -100 is 'fatal error' which basically means 'somethign bad happened', probably during startup.